# Running multiple apps on NGINX subfolders

Tags: nginx, next.js

I have an NGINX server and two frontend apps: A and B deployed using Docker Compose.

App A is a Next.js app that should be accessible at `/product/a` and the same for App B accessible at `/product/b`.

I have a working NGINX config for A:

```
worker_processes 1;
 
events { worker_connections 1024; }
 
http {
  server {
        listen 80;

        server_name saasbase.dev;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        
    location /_next/static {
            rewrite (.*) \/products\/a\/$1 break;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
  
    location ~ ^/products/a(.*) {
            proxy_pass http://a:3007$1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

The trouble is Next.js makes calls to `_next/static` to get some js files. Currently, because there is only one app I can redirect the calls to that location to go into the A app. If I add the B app, it will also request its js files from `_next/static` and get mixed up.

Is there a way to keep them separate?

Comment: Use correct [`basePath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath) for both of them and remove that ugly `rewrite` workaround. That way all you would need is `location /product/a { proxy_pass ... }` and `location /product/b { proxy_pass ... }`

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your comment, but I tried to do following your instructions, but dont' work for me, Please, share more informations and code here. Regards.